# trouble with Logitech mk270 combo keyboard/mouse with USB 3.0 hub

Tags: wireless, usb, keyboard, mouse, logitech

I have been checking for solutions on this forum and others, but so far I cannot find a problem that match mine.
Basically I have a Logitech mk270 combo keyboard/mouse which work fine under Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS when plugged to a USB 2.0 hub, but only works with Windows when I use a USB 3.0 hub. This is strange, because the USB 3.0 hub appears correctly with the command lsusb -v -t with a speed of 5000M ("SuperSpeed" = USB 3.0) and if I plug a USB 3.0 memory stick then it works fine at USB 3.0 speed.
I don't understand why the receiver of the Logitech is not recognise/work... any thoughts?
Cheers,
Rv

Answer (score 2):

There are TWO different kinds of MK270. Unifying- and not. The latter has some other less universal radio system on the same band. I have the latter. Seems that my mouse generally works with a bit of lag, but tolerable. Keybord, not so much. Expect this to be a dead end unless someone more talented in writing drivers gets involved. :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get a Logitech mouse/keyboard to work - same thing, works fine in windows but not in ubuntu.

After 2 months of messing with it and finding no resolution on here, I have to fall back to the Logitech response (also took them 2 months to figure it out) and that is "Logitech products do not work with Linux."

That was the final answer from their tech support - second tier or some such fancy name, as well as a phone call also to their second tier support.

I replaced them with $5.00 worth of no-brand USB mouse and keyboard from the bargain bin at Wal-Mart, and have not had a bit of trouble since.

Comment: Hi, Well actually for me the keyboard and mouse work perfectly fine in Ubuntu but only if the receiver is plugged on a USB 2.0 port not with a USB 3.0 port, so it has nothing to do with the Logitech keyboard, mouse or receiver, but the way the receiver is recognised through the USB port...

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood.  After all the heartache I went through, I am suprised it works at all under Ubuntu; logitech was pretty adamant about it!